# dowloading the twitter 1.10.0 for python

Tags: python, twitter

i am trying to install through windows power shell and i get this error

C:\Users-\desktop\dist\twitter-1.10.0> python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1, in 
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
PS C:\Users-\desktop\dist\twitter-1.10.0>

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the Traceback says, you have no `setuptools` module installed. You can download it [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and install it invoking `python ez_setup.py` from the directory where you have downloaded the file.